# Etherpad: how to make it run under a domain?

Tags: debian, etherpad

right now I have /etc/etherpad/bin/run.sh

however, it says it's starting the server at 0.0.0.0:90001

how do I make it point tomydomain.com ?

Comment: I believe this belongs to ServerFault instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means that your etherpad server is listening for clients (webbrowsers) on all IP numbers that your machine has. The number after the colon is the port number. Try going to http://localhost:90001/ from a webbrowser on the server for a first test.
For how to use a domain name, you really need to know something about DNS or otherwise pay someone to set up DNS for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use a reverse proxy https://github.com/Pita/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-put-Etherpad-Lite-behind-a-reverse-Proxy

Comment: yes, if in case security/performance is important then a frontend webserver is a great idea. The process should be similar with both Etherpad 1.1 and the new reimplementation Etherpad Lite from Pita.